# Add NSDictionary items to NSMutableAray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

How to insert NSDictionary items to NSMutableAray and get there count.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    storeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:strResponseData error:NULL];
    NSArray *list = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"NAME"];
    for (NSDictionary *lesson in list){
        [listArray addObject:[lesson objectForKey:@"VALUE"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Count %d",[listArray count]);
}
```

Crash Log

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:**

The above code i have done its crashes for me.

Comment: There is an issue in your JOSN or the parsing of it. When you call `[lesson objectForKey:@"VALUE"]` it is return `nil` which can not be added to an array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not being unable to store an `NSDictionary` into the array, but rather, inserting an object that is `nil`.

Your parsing either didn't pass at some point, or you didn't get the objects you expected, so I'd put some breakpoints and check what the objects you're working are really, and what is stored inside.

Additionally, you haven't initialized your `listArray` anywhere, and that might be another issue as well.

Comment: Thanks i have cross check my JSON object which have missed one more attribute.